# Jungle Disk vs DiskAgent

Tags: backup, amazon-s3, amazon-web-services, jungledisk

I'm looking at implementing a secure off-site data backup of about 100 GB (and growing), more than likely on Amazon S3.  I haven't found many reviews of DiskAgent, has anybody had a good experience with it?  Seems to be significantly more expensive than Jungle Disk, so I'm curious to know why and if it's worth it.

Can either of these run syncing processes as a service?  Or are both GUI based?

Answer (score 1):

Once you've set up the Jungle Disk server client, you can manage it remotely as far as scheduling, one-offs, etc, so you don't have to use a local GUI on the server.

I don't have any experience with DiskAgent, but JungleDisk has encryption, scheduling, etc, and you can back it up to Rackspace Cloud Files which is a bit cheaper than using S3 (no transfer charges).

Disclaimer: I work for Rackspace, which owns JungleDisk, but I don't have anything to do with that part of the company.  I use JungleDisk to backup all my Linux and Windows machines at home.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  I've been trying out Jungle Disk today and there's a lot I like about it.  I still haven't decided which way to go though.  I don't like the dependency on the Jungle Disk service to restore files, but DiskAgent is not any different in that regard.

Answer (score 1):

DiskAgent works very well and seems to be used by the professional community. There have been a number of positive reviews by numerous people in the healthcare and financial services space. We chose it because of the flexibility, excellent support, and high regard for security. We found them because they are a strategic partner/resource from Scottrade Advisor community. There are a lot of backup providers but not very many that work really well. Jungle Disk and DropBox seem fine too but their support is not very good. I also don't think that the other providers are willing to execute confidentiality agreements the people at DiskAgent gladly signed a confidentiality agreement with our group - a requirement for our relationships. One other thing I liked about DiskAgent is that you can backup content selectively to your own networked resource for no charge.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  I haven't found much discussion of it other than the AWS case study, though that speaks well for it.  The biggest problem I have with DiskAgent is a hard requierment on the service to access the backups, since they don't use your own S3 buckets.  Jungle Disk will use your own S3 bucket, but it's in a native format, so you'll still need to login to Jungle Disk to download your backups, which doesn't offer much improvement over the DiskAgent approach, but it is nice to see something in your S3 buckets.